# Question about more time is required to transcribe audio file to text

Tags: whisper, avaudiofile

Regarding to above title, I am using whisper module to transcribe audio file to text but more time is taking this process in python.

I am trying to convert audio file to text in minimum time, below is the that I am using

```
def transcribe_audio(filename): 
        print(filename)
        location =    r"C:\Users\shree\Desktop\projects\Summarization_project\Point_Extraction\media\audio_files"
        file_path = os.path.join(location, filename)
        model = whisper.load_model('tiny')
        result = model.transcribe(file_path, fp16=False)
        text = result['text']
        text = auto_correct_text(text)
        print(text)
        os.remove(file_path)
        print(f"Deleted: {filename}")
        return text
```

Comment: What are you comparing the time to? Are you saying why it is taking so long?

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, the `tiny` model should be the fastest model, so any other model will be slower. How long is the audio file you are transcribing? How many minutes? Are you using a GPU or `cuda` or CPU only? How long does it take?

Comment: hello , I am trying to transcribe audio file of 50 min duration audio file and I have CPU only

Comment: @drum, yes whisper takes more time to transcribe 50 min or larger audio files and want to transcribe in few seconds, is it possible